# Can Not find Button & gridview Control in Toolbox In .Net Core WinForm App

Tags: winforms, .net-core

i a problem
i updated visual studio latest version.

but !
Can Not find Button & gridview Control in Toolbox In .Net Core WinForm App

of course the previews version i have this problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqUjC.png)

Comment: Please post your Visual Studio version number and .NET Core version number. Also, GridView is not available for .NET Core, only .NET (Classic).

Answer (score 0):

To restore the Button control, see the following excerpt from the [announcement of the Windows Forms Designer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/windows-forms-designer-for-net-core-released/);

> Some users might not see some controls (like Button, CheckBox, etc.)
>   in the Toolbox. That happens due to the Toolbox cache corruption issue
>   that will be fixed in the next version.  Meanwhile, there is a simple
>   way to fix it on your machine:
>
> Right-click on the Toolbox > Choose Items… In the Choose Toolbox Items
>   dialog click “Reset” button This should fix the problem.

GridView does not exist in .NET Core, but DataGridView will be released in the future. See announcement.